# How to redirect to new page from drop down in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I want o create a drop-down list besides with GO button. In such a way that when i click on first item from drop down list it should redirect to first item information html page with help of GO button which i created besides drop down list. Same way if i click on second item from drop down list it should redirect to second item information html page and so on.

Comment: You can do this in onchange event of drop-down

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ng-change="redirectTo()" tag to your `<select>` that triggers a function in your controller. In the controller, check the the model to know where to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your routing mechanism, but say you just use the simple `$window.location` , you can do something like this:

```
<select ng-options="route as route for route in routes"
        ng-model="goToRoute"></select>
<button ng-click="redirectToRoute()">Go!</button>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.routes = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.somesite.com"];

$scope.redirectToRoute = function() {
    // redirect logic
    var route = $scope.goToRoute;
    $window.location.href = route;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwwLq6ub/2/)

```
<select ng-change='redirectTo("login")' ng-model="goto"></select>
```

On change you need to add following code snippet

If you are using

```
$routeProvider
```

then use

```
$location.url('#/home'); // without params
$location.url('#/home/123'); // with params
```

or if you are using

```
$stateProvider
```

then use

```
$state.go('home'); // without params
$state.go('home', {id:123}); // with params
```

Comment: I have build sample jsfiddle so have look https://jsfiddle.net/cwwLq6ub/1/